# Access current column and row information in Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap, facet-grid

I am plotting a FacetGrid of heatmaps with the seaborn package in python.

Now I want to overlay each heatmap with a hatch depending on the heatmap-tile value following this example:

[adding hatches to seaborn heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55285013/adding-hatches-to-seaborn-heatmap-plot)

My function, which defines if a cell is hatched or not depends on the row and column information of the FacetGrid

```
def draw_heatmap(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.pop('color')
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    d = data.pivot(index=args[1], columns=args[0], values=args[2])
    d = d.sort_index(ascending=False)
    sns.heatmap(d, **kwargs)


d = np.array(
    np.meshgrid(np.arange(1, 6, 1),
                np.arange(6, 11, 1),
                np.arange(1, 6, 1),
                np.arange(6, 11, 1))).T.reshape(-1, 4)
d = np.c_[d, np.random.randint(1, 5, 625)]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
fg = sns.FacetGrid(df,
                   col='b',
                   row='a',
                   margin_titles=True,
                   height=5,
                   aspect=1)
fg = fg.map_dataframe(draw_heatmap,
                      'c',
                      'd',
                      'e',
                      cbar=False,
                      cmap='viridis',
                      annot=True,
                      fmt=".0f",
                      linewidths=.5)
```

Now, depending on the values of `'b', 'a'` and `'values'`, where `'b', 'a'` are rows and columns of the FacetGrid and `'values'` are the values of the pivot tabel in the `draw_heatmap` function, I want to apply a mask.

```
# fgA and fgB are the input values coming from the FacetGrid
hatch = data.stack().to_frame().apply(lambda x: myFunc(fgA, fgB, x.name[0], x.name[1]), axis=1).unstack()
x = np.arange(len(data.columns)+1)
y = np.arange(len(data.index)+1)
zm = np.ma.masked_less(hatch.values, 5)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(w, cmap='viridis', annot=True, fmt=".0f", linewidths=.5, ax=ax)
ax.pcolor(x, y, zm, hatch='//', alpha=0.)
```

How can I realize this and access the FacetGrid information while plotting the single heatmaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the axes object within the FacetGrid using the `axes` attribute. It's an array of all the axes in your FacetGrid.

```
fg.axes[b, a].pcolor(x, y, zm, hatch='//', alpha=0.)
```